# You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

```
Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components.
```

In android studio, while running my first program I got above warning.
then I searched over internet and I got some solution to this problem, which is:

```
C:\Users\KIIT\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app>flutter config --android-studio-dir \C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

So, I tried this config method. but still nothing happened, and it showed me "*You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings*." this.
please help me.

Comment: If you have done everything right. try invalidate cache and restart on the Menu -> File -> invalidate cache and restart. Some times you may have problem in your environment setup.

Comment: This might help you as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62858734/13685592

Comment: Before you post, search the site to make sure your question hasn’t been answered
1.Summarize the problem
2.Provide details and any research
3.When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

Comment: did you run flutter doctor? what is its output?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22649) related to this.

Here are some references on how to resolve this issue. (Taken from the GitHub issue mentioned above):

One option is to try [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22649#issuecomment-450020266):

> try to use this command
> `flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk` after that you have to try this command
> `flutter doctor --android-licenses` after that accept all the licenses after
> that try `flutter doctor`

Another [option](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22649#issuecomment-520472515):

> all you need to do is install Android API level 29 (Android 9.0+ "Q")
> go to ***Setting > Android SDK >SDK platform>Check Android 9+*** and
> Press Apply button after that android studio will pop up a dialog to
> install what you downloaded(Android 9+) then you are done

And [take note](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22649#issuecomment-541270799):

> In Android Studio, ensure that the API level of your Project SDK
> (***File->Project Structure***) <= of the API level of your AVD.